# How can I extract the which a or b in perl regex matching /(a|b)/

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match different logic expression, such as: "`$a and $b`" using Perl regex, here is my code:

```
$input =~ /^(.*)\s(and|or|==|<|>|>=|<=)\s(.*)$/ {
        $arg1=$1;
        $arg2=$3;
        $opt=$2;
}
```

and my purpose is to get:

```
$arg1="$ARGV[0]=~/\w{4}/"
$arg2="$num_arg==1"
$opt ="and"
```

I want to get the exact value matched in the or expression. I don't want to do the same thing for all the cases to match one by one, and hardcode the operator.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: What is a typical value of `$input`? Please add it to your question.

Comment: Your code is not valid Perl 5 code. `perl` reports a `syntax error at ... line 1`. Please post code which correctly compiles.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how `$a and $b` could be mapped to the values of `$arg1` and `$arg2` you posted, and how either relates to the title of the question? Please provide the actual value of `$input` you provide the code, and the actual values of `$arg1` and `$arg2` you're expecting. Also note that depending on what you want to do in fine, regexes may not be the best option.

Comment: Try change `(.*)` to `(.*?)`

Comment: Parsing numerical expressions properly would seem to call for an expression parser, not a regular expression. Regex is fine for lexical analysis e.g. for separating atomic symbols, but quickly crumbles when a symbol could have different meanings depending on context

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
$input = '$ARGV[0]=~/\w{4}/ and $num_arg==1';
if ($input=~/^(.*)\s(and|or|==|<|>|>=|<=)\s(.*)$/) {
        $arg1=$1;
        $arg2=$3;
        $opt=$2;
        print "$arg1\n$arg2\n$opt\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a little parser able to reveal the structure of a logical expression. That is because you may have another expression inside a term. You can use perl to test your grammar using [Marpa::R2](http://search.cpan.org/~jkegl/Marpa-R2-3.000000/) package.

As a first attempt I would write:

```
<expression> ::= <term> | <expression> <binary-op> <term>
<term> ::= <factor> <binary-op> <factor> | <unary-op><factor>
<factor> ::= <id>
<binary-op> ::= (and|or|==|<|>|>=|<=)
<unary-op> ::= (not | ! )
```

One thing for sure that you can't complete describe the syntax of a logical expression using only regular expressions, it will always lack some valid case.

**The Perl Code for validation**

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Marpa::R2;

my $dsl = <<'END_OF_DSL';
:default ::= action => [name,values]
lexeme default = latm => 1

Expression       ::= Term
                     | Expression BinaryOP Term
Term             ::= Factor BinaryOP Factor
                     | UnaryOP Factor
Factor           ::= ID
ID                ~ [\w]+
BinaryOP          ~ 'and' | 'or' | '==' | '<' | '>' | '>=' | '<='
UnaryOP           ~ 'not' | '!' 
:discard          ~ whitespace
whitespace        ~ [\s]+
END_OF_DSL

# your input
my $input       = 'a and b or !c';

# your parser
my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new( { source => \$dsl } );

# process input
my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new(
    { grammar => $grammar, semantics_package => 'My_Actions' } );
my $length_read = $recce->read( \$input );

die "Read ended after $length_read of ", length $input, " characters"
  if $length_read != length $input;
```